# Duplicate quadratic Bézier curve with new start point?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces, bezier-curve

I have Bézier curve as shown by the wikipedia gif here: [image]

I would like to create a new curve that is a segment of the old one. For example, in this gif (from the same article):

[image]

.. **if I wanted B to be the starting point of the new curve, but for the curve to follow the same path, how could I find the new control point?**

I can see that the answer is very straightforward and easily solvable, but my mind still hasn't caught up with the logic behind the equation for the quadratic Bézier curve:

[image]

so I'm having trouble thinking it out. I would greatly appreciate any hints/advice that would help push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Generically, this process is known as [*De Casteljau* subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm): it turns out that the process of (recursively) evaluating the curve at a given point leads to new sets of control points representing the curves on either side of that point.  In your case, in the process of evaluating $B=B(t)$ from $P_0$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ we build the following structure:

- $Q_0 = (1-t) P_0 + t P_1$
- $Q_1 = (1-t) P_1 + t P_2$
- $B = (1-t) Q_0 + tQ_1$

It then turns out that the two pieces of the curve to either side of $B$ can be represented by the curves with control points $(P_0, Q_0, B)$ and $(B, Q_1, P_2)$ (each over the interval $(0..1)$, of course), respectively.  Proving this is a grind through the algebra, but it's a fairly instructive one - I definitely recommend trying it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you know $Q_0$:

Note that since $Q_0$ is on the line $\overline{P_0P_1}$, we can write $Q_0=(1-k)P_0+kP_1$ for some $k$, $0\leq k\leq1$, which has to be determined. To have the same curve, you also require $Q_1=(1-k)P_1+kP_2$.

Then, the original bezier curve is traced out by varying $t$ from $0$ to $1$. You can get the segment by varying $t$ from $k$ to $1$ to trace out the curve from $B$ to $P_2$.

More than likely, you don't know $Q_0$, but only $B$.

Since the bezier curve traces out the line
$$
   C(t) = (1-t)^2P_0+2t(1-t)P_1+t^2P_2,
$$
by solving $B=(1-t)^2P_0+2t(1-t)P_1+t^2P_2$ for $t$, you get the beginning of the range for which $t$ will vary. This must have a solution, since $B$ is on the curve $C(t)$. I have called this $k$ above.

Comment: Sorry, meant B to be the starting point.

Comment: @Walkerneo In order to keep the same shaple of the curve, you need the same control points. What you need to do to get a segment of the curve it to change the domain of $t$. In my description above, I describe how to get an appropriate domain for $t$ for your problem.

Comment: @Daryl In fact, that's just not true - you can actually define new control points that will give you either segment of the curve, and those control points fall naturally out of the process for evaluating the curve at the given point.  You don't need to keep track of domains of $t$ at all.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I didn't say it was the *only* way, but it is one method.

Comment: @Daryl -- I'd say that your use of the word "need" (twice) suggests that the solution you proposed is the only one. Anyway, whatever you meant to imply, restricting the domain is not the only approach. In fact, it's not even the usual approach. Most people would calculate new control points using the de Casteljau algorithm, as StevenS suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The middle control point of a quadratic Bézier curve lies at the intersection of the tangents to the curve at the two outer control points, so in theory to find the middle control point for a subdivision of the curve, you simply have to compute those tangents and their intersection. In your illustration, the line segment $\overline{Q_0Q_1}$ is tangent to the curve at $B$, so the new control point is either $Q_0$ or $Q_1$ depending on which side of $B$ you wanted.

However, there’s no need to do all that. Recall that the parameter $t$ represents the proportional distance moved along the line segments that are used to construct a Bézier curve. That is, $$\begin{align}Q_0&=(1-t)P_0+tP_1 \\ Q_1&=(1-t)P_1+tP_2 \\ B&=(1-t)Q_0+tQ_1.\end{align}$$ So, if you have the value of $t$ that corresponds to the new endpoint $B$, computing the new middle control point is trivial. In fact, depending on how you’re generating the curve, you might already have it.

If, on the other hand, you only have a point $B$ known to be on the curve, then you can solve solve the resulting pair of quadratic equations for $t$ and plug that into the above equation for $Q_0$ or $Q_1$. Alternatively, with a bit of work you can find expressions for the slope of the tangent at $B$ as a function of $B$’s coordinates and those of the original control points only, but you’ll have to figure out a way to choose the correct sign of the square roots involved to get the right slope. Once you have it, you can compute the intersection of the tangents, but I think solving for $t$ directly is less work.